# Jdbc based Queue Channel without poller. Possible?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a scenario where I would like to separate the flow into a number of transactions. I am using queue channels based on a JdbcChannelMessageStore to do so and that works excellent. Its robust and it just works. But because these Jdbc  based queues (the database) are polled by the executors, I get a natural limitation on the throughput (I don't really want to configure the poller to poll every 1 millisecond). So my question is this, is there a way for the queue channel to notify the consumer of that channel that a new messages has been queued, and then trigger the "poller" to have a look in the database to see what has to be consumed?

So the simple scenario:
1. A queue channel where someone puts a message
2. A service activator that will process that message (in parallel)

```
<int:channel id="InputChannel">
   <int:queue message-store="jdbcChannelStore"/>
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="TradeTransformerExecutor" pool-size="2-20" queue-capacity="20" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<int:service-activator id="TradeConverter" input-channel="InputChannel" output-channel="TradeChannel" method="transform">
   <beans:bean class="com.service.TradeConverter"/>
   <int:poller task-executor="TradeTransformerExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="-1" receive-timeout="0" fixed-rate="100">
      <int:transactional transaction-manager="dbTransactionManager"/>
   </int:poller>
    </int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="TradeChannel"></int:channel>
```

So how could I make this InputChannel notify the poller (or something else) to start executing the message right away and not wait for 100ms? 
Also I don't want to use DirectChannels as I do want some persistence between defined flows for robustness reasons.

Cheers guys.

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change a trigger on demand; you can have a dynamic trigger, but changes only take effect after the next poll.

Instead of using a JDBC-backed channel, consider using an outbound channel adapter to store the data and a JDBC outbound gateway (with just a query, no update).

Use a pub-sub channel and, after storing, send the message (perhaps via a bridged ExecutorChannel) to the gateway.

Alternatively, simply inject your queue channel into a service and invoke it via a `<service-activator/>`. You would need a pub-sub channel bridged to your queue channel, with the second subscriber being the service activator which, when it receives the message calls `receive()` on the channel.

Finally, consider using a JMS, or RabbitMQ backed-channel for high performance persistence instead - they are much better a queueing than a database.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'll give it a try. It might be that in the future I will replace the jdbc with an actual JMS broker. But I just thought there might be something there alreadly, as I assume the claim-check pattern must do something like this (store to the database and then send a "ticket" to the consumer).

Though one thing I don't understand with your alternative. How could I create a queue channel without defining a poller to it? Because if I understand it correctly the recieve() will be called by the bean in the service activator and no one else?

Comment: Correct; instead of polling the queue, you will be calling `receive()` on-demand - presumably on a new thread, downstream of an executor channel - the input message to the service activator will be discarded and the output message will be the one you received from the channel.